# Searching cell values in next cell

Tags: excel

```
Column1   Column2                  Column3      Column4
A         4573925208184160         4630         I
B         4573925208184800         4460         C
C         4573925208184260         4800         F
D         4573925208184460         3970         B
E         4573925208184730         4230         G
F         4573925208184180         4260         J
G         4573925208184440         4730         K
H         4573925208184150         4850         M
I         4573925208184230         4160         E
J         4573925208183970         4180         D
K         4573925208184630         4440         A
L         4573925208184550         4390         N
M         4573925208184850         4150         H
N         4573925208184390         4550         L
```

I am new in excel tool and want to find last 4 digits of column2 in column3. If found then want to show column1 value in column4.

Let's see: for first row, last 4 digits of column2 value is '4160'. It is present in front of I. So column4 value is I.

Comment: Are you aware that the numbers in column B are 16 digits wide. Excel has a 15 digit precision and may have rounded those off to the left-most 15 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair should so, providing you use the [RIGHT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267EE-9AFA-4639-A02B-F19E1786CF2F) to peel off the right 4 digits from the longer number in column B.

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(--RIGHT(B1, 4),C:C, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place this formula in column 4:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(VALUE(RIGHT(B2,4)),$C$2:$C$15,0))`

The formula assumes your data starts in cell A1 with the column 1 - 4 as headers.

The `Index` function will return the corresponding value in Column 1 for the `Match` of the `Right` 4 most characters for the value in column 2 against the values in column 3.